# Why ASUS 'Device Discovery Utility' needed when making it an AP?

Tags: wireless-router, wireless-access-point, asus-laptop

Have ASUS AC1700 wireless router that will be turned into an Access Point (AP), and the instruction say I will need to use (download) the Devise Discovery tool to find the AP address?

1)Why is this necessary?

2)Is this a common practice with other brands (NG) with making the unit an AP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you set a router into access point mode, it no longer appears at the same address that it used to unless a fixed IP is used.  Without a fixed IP, it will (attempt to) use DHCP to obtain an IP address like any other device or computer on the network.

If you need access to the device, e.g. to disable AP mode, as it's not a PC with a screen and keyboard, you'll need to connect to the device over the network, and to do so, you will need to know the address that it now sits at.

The easiest way to do this in a home network is to login to the device running the DHCP server (probably your router) and look at the address allocation table for the devices on the network.  However, the variations in hardware, firmware, possible lack of access to the device... these all conspire to make that difficult to add to a guide.

Instead, the instructions are directing you to use a specific tool that can scan the network to discover the devices and addresses in use on the network.
This allows the writer to provide instructions that apply to all users, and bypasses any issues to do with differing software and hardware setups.

Comment: 1)is this common for other brands (Netgear...) where they need to use a tool to find the new address the the IP created so the log onto the devise?
2)with the IP created address, does it change so everytime you want to log onto the devices you first have to find another new address?
3)when people create an AP, do most of them set so IP creates new address, or do most people make it a static address?

Comment: Setting addresses on devices is common behaviour across all devices - it has to be to work.  The assigned address is leased.  The duration of that lease is defined by the DHCP server, after which time it _may_ be changed - it depends on the implementation. Most will just renew the lease though, keeping the same address.  The choice of a static or dynamic address is a choice, if the device gives it to you.  DHCP is "easier" in that there is no manual address configuration, it avoids address conflicts etc.

Comment: @laurayuan - The software is not required to find the device.  It's just easier then trying to explain to your average Joe how to find a device on their network.  If you don't need the tool to find the device, once you made the configuration change, you are free not to use it.

Comment: Thanks to those who took the time...pretty much answered my question.

Comment: @laurayuan good :) you can mark the answer as accepted to show that.